# Any way to customize size/position of logo in Firebase AuthUI?

Tags: android, xml, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

No matter what I try, my logo in FirebaseAuthUI is blurry. I've tried correcting this (as well as repositioning it, as it appears way at the top) by changing its size and by editing its style using this block in my styles.xml file:

```
 <style name="FirebaseUI.AuthMethodPicker.Logo">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>

    </style>
```

Changing its size does not affect the distortion, and making any changes in styles .xml or values .xml have no apparent effect. Is there any way to make these adjustments to the logo without building a login activity myself?

Answer (score 0):

Add and play with this value to change the size of the logo:

```
 <style name="FirebaseUI.AuthMethodPicker.Logo">
     ...
     <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
 </style>
```